# Joins across more than two tables with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

A while ago I asked (Joins across multiple tables with ActiveRecord with named scopes) [Joins across multiple tables with ActiveRecord with named scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189086/joins-across-multiple-tables-with-activerecord-with-named-scopes)

Now I need to create a named scope that involved joining across more than two tables, eg:

```
named_scope :baz_category, lambda {|c| {:joins=>([:foo,:bar,:baz]):conditions=>['baz_cat=',c]}}
```

Where Foo has one Bar and Bar has one Baz.

I'd like a solution to work for a 4th or 5th etc table.

many many thanks to whoever helps me with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`named_scope :baz_category, lambda { |c| :joins => {:foo => { :bar => :baz } }`

Nest as deep as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using [eager loading](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)? Documentation is verbose with good examples.

Comment: So in Foo, I'll tell that to include Bar and tell Bar to include Baz, making it very easy to jump from Foo to Baz?